# Fill Grid Using Type Script Controller

Tags: angularjs, typescript, typescript1.4, typescript1.5

I have implemented a controller using typescript and angular js and getting data in response as well but there is some problem when i am trying to bind that data with my grid.I have used ng-repeater for it.

I have declared my controller on html page as :-

```
ng-controller="CustomerCtrl as custom"
```

And i am trying to access it in my controller as :-

```
 ng-repeat="cust in custom.cust_File
```

and than

```
 Full Name: {{cust.Name}}
```

I don't know where the problem exactly...

Comment: Try to put your properties at the class level and not on the $scope, as the content of custom in your view will be a CustomerCtrl. If you leave things as is, I think your ng-repeat should be ng-repeat="cust in custom.$scope.cust_File".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using cust in custom.$scope.cust_File as described by @hugues Stefanski. 
Thanx a lot....